# Can't Set Up Cocos2dx [Android, Eclipse, Windows]

Tags: android, game-engine, cocos2d-x

After I have set up the cocos2d-x development environment for Android in Eclipse on Windows through [this tutorial](http://www.multigesture.net/articles/how-to-setup-cocos2d-x-windows-and-android), I thought I have settled everything down and ready for development except I can't copy the sample project into my own workspace .. (Still Can't) ..

But, later I found [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started),  .. It is for setting up cocos2dx for android in Eclipse on iOS .. 
In the next tutorial, the author didn't use Cgywin or MinGW anymore.. He just set up with Android NDK ..

What I'm curious is

1. There are a lot of differences between 1st tutorial and 2nd tutorial. Is that just because of the 2nd tutorial is only meant for iOS ?
2. I don't see any CPP file except in here "`jni/hellocpp/main.cpp`" in the project content "`org.cocos2dx.hellocpp.HelloCpp`" project. But, the 2nd author mentioned a lot of CPP files in his tutorial. Why ? Because of the cocos2dx version difference ?
3. When I open `main.cpp` file, it shows a lot of errors.. Almost all of those are `xxx could not be resolved`. I have already added `..\cocos2dx\include` path and `..\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include` path correctly. Why ?
4. I literally can't run the sample program.. It said `java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` .. and in Logcat `don't support gles2.0` .. Why ? Is that because my JVM is Java SE 7 Server Version ? The first author mentioned "JavaSE 7" won't work with cocos2dx. It only work with "JavaSE 6" .. But, I still have other Android application projects which depends on "JavaSE 7" .. How can I run the sample project in "JavaSE 7" ??

Sorry for the 1001 questions .. I'm totally a newbie to cocos2dx and really eager to work something with it .. :-)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks @InSane .. I will use better RTF Next Time .. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for answers, here are some:

1) The "cannot resolve" errors are actually false, and based on eclipse's buggy predictions. You should turn off this error reporting (see the second tutorial link you have, it shows you how at the end).

2) I have recently used cocos2d-x 2.x, and (to my surprise) it doesn't support running on the AVD. I bought a cheap old Galaxy S of of eBay, and the app ran fine on that.

3) you don't see the cpp files, cause they are added only in the make file initially. You must do some extra work to make them appear in eclipse. (Again, check the second tutorial).